# Reprojecting a shape to UTM33

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I still have trouble reprojecting shapefiles :(

I would like to reproject it to UTM33N / WGS84 (EPSG 32633) I think the projection of the shapefile might be Pulkovo 1984/ Gauss-Krüger Zone 4 (EPSG 2398) or ETRS89 / UTM33N (EPSG 25833) http://projektidee.org/images/extern/ffh.zip

I failed to reproject it though...

Could anyone here help me with that?

I'm trying to do this with QGIS.

What I do is right click on layer an save as - then I choose the Projection system UTM33N/WGS84 and save the file to a new shapefile.

The other thing was to first assign the other projection (pulkovo) to the shape layer and then save it to a new shapefile.

With both ways of dealing with it I didn't succeed...

Comment: can you tell us what you have tried.

Comment: Also can you tell us the GIS software you were using to do this?

Comment: Yes sorry. I'm trying to do this with Qgis.

What I do is right click on layer an save as - then I choose the Projection system UTM33N/WGS84 and save the file to a new shape.

The other thing was to first assign the other projection (pulkovo) to the shape layer and then save it to a new shape file.

With both ways of dealing with it I didn't succeed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little something wrong with your shapefile. I think it is supposed to be EPSG:32633 but the x-ordinates have been shifted by 33,000,000 metres (just to make this clear, this is 33 million metres). I can't imagine how this happened, but I think you need to do an affine transformation using the qgsAffine plug-in, deducting 33,000,000 from the x ordinate of every vertex in the shapefile.

I've done this and the result appears to map onto the real world slightly better than did the original shapefile, see the picture below. Does this fit look good enough? Nick.

[image]

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you very much! This should be fine I think. 
As I've never worked with this qgis plugin - do you have the result file still on your coumputer and would it be trouble to send it to me via email. That would be extremely nice! christ.stark [a-n-t-i-s-p-a-m] @ gmx.de